# как перевести resText в переменную типа int

Tags: java, android

```
 TextView resText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

как перевести  resText  в переменную типа int

Answer (score 1):

Никак.

**resText** у вас со значением **TextView**. Соответственно так оно и останется.
Единственное из **resText** можно получить идентификатор (будет равен в данном случае *R.id.textView*), вот так: **resText.getId()**

*Хотя, может я не правильно понял что вы хотите...*

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView resText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
int x = Integer.parseInt(resText.getText().toString());
```

*Не забудьте сделать проверку, когда будете класть текст объекта `TextView` в `int` на целочисленный тип, иначе получите исключение.*

Answer (score 0):

```
resText.getId()
```

Это позволит получить целое число, которое является идентификатором вашего `View`, или же `R.id.textView` в числовом представлении.

Если же вам нужно преобразовать текст, который находится в переменной resText в переменную типа `int`, то это можно сделать следующим способом:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt(resText.getText().toString());
```